# Single <select> has multiple selected options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My  tag is a single-choice pulldown, the default behavior for a  tag. I have three values in it, "No", "Yes", "All". I am trying to change the selected  programmatically, as I have done a thousand times before, with the following code (I'm using JQuery 1.9.1):

```
$('#select').children(':selected').removeAttr('selected');
$('#select').children('option[value="yes"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('#select').children(':selected');
```

I don't even know how this is possible, but somehow, in Chrome 26.0.1410.65 running on 10.8.3, there will be two selected options. Only one of them will show in the UI, but the last line of code will return two elements.

This does work correctly in Firefox 16.0.2, so I am mystified. Does anyone know if this is a quirk of Chrome, or if this is correct behavior and it's just changed?

Comment: `selected` is a property, use the .prop method and true/false as the value.

Comment: What's the point of this line `$('#select').children(':selected');`?

Comment: @j08691 as the post says,  it's to point out that more that more than one value comes back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this to select desired value

```
 $('#select').val('yes');
```

Answer (score 2):

Stop trying to manipulate properties using attribute methods! Older versions of jQuery let you do this, but newer ones won't.

```
$('#select').children(':selected').prop("selected",false);
$('#select').children('option[value="yes"]').prop("selected",true);
//$('#select').children(':selected');
```

Though `.val()` as pointed out by Mohammad Adil is a better way of handling this.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the `selected` attribute to change what option is selected. Instead, use the `selectedIndex` property of your dropdwn.

For instance, in your case you might want this:

```
document.getElementById('select').selectedIndex = 1;
```